# PHP system() help no simple commands work

Tags: php, shell, system

I am trying to run a shell from one of my controllers in a PHP codeigniter applications,

I am trying to run the file `/x/sh/xpay4.sh` however I just get 127 returned to the screen, I can even use basic commands like `ls` or `pwd` can any suggest why this would be, I thought it might be safe_mode when I `ini_get('safe_mode')` it returns 1

Comment: Does your PHP user have the permissions to execute xpay4.sh?

Comment: how do I find out my PHP user?

Comment: whoami tells who you are (as user), then to check permission I think ls -l could give you the answer about permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system` function is restricted in safe mode.

> You can only execute executables
>   within the `safe_mode_exec_dir`. For
>   practical reasons it's currently not
>   allowed to have `..` components in the
>   path to the executable.
>   `escapeshellcmd`() is executed on the
>   argument of this function.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php

Answer (score 0):

system() returns only the last line of the shell output.
Sounds likt this is "127".

If you need the whole output instead, try:

```
$output = array();
exec('/x/sh/xpay4.sh', $output);
echo implode("<br>", $output);
```